# Ruby on rails bundler and github ssl error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, windows-10, railsinstaller

Recently started having this issue: when trying to run bundle update or install I get

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nomaddc/country_select.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Retrying `git clone "https://github.com/nomaddc/country_select.git" "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/cache/bundler/git/country_select-db5df4c320ea31e458a287fae5e692ca9b00cf24" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone "https://github.com/nomaddc/country_select.git" "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/cache/bundler/git/country_select-db5df4c320ea31e458a287fae5e692ca9b00cf24" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory c:/Sites/BRICS has failed.fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nomaddc/country_select.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

that github being my branch of country_select. Any idea what's worng and how to fix it? I'm running RailsInstaller version under windows 10.

Commenting out that gem allows to run command just fine, but I can't drop it from project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `https://` to `git://`

else it could be because of that change :

> On February 8, 2018 we’ll start disabling the following:
>
> TLSv1/TLSv1.1: This applies to all HTTPS connections, including web,
>   API, and git connections to https://github.com and
>   https://api.github.com. diffie-hellman-group1-sha1: This applies to
>   all SSH connections to github.com diffie-hellman-group14-sha1: This
>   applies to all SSH connections to github.com We’ll disable the
>   algorithms in two stages:
>
> February 8, 2018 19:00 UTC (11:00 am PST): Disable deprecated
>   algorithms for one hour February 22, 2018 19:00 UTC (11:00 am PST):
>   Permanently disable deprecated algorithms

so you can update your git client and try to push it again (it should work then).

Good luck!

Comment: Changing https:// to git:// indeed worked! Oddly enough I didn't have same issue on Ubuntu machine, just on windows.